# Почему не создается связь Many to Many?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, миграция

Есть следующие классы

```
public class Act
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int OperationId {get;set;}

    public virtual Operation {get;set;}
}

public class Operation
{    
    public int Id {get;set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Program> Programs {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Act> Acts {get;set;}    
}

public class Program
{    
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int? ActId {get;set;}
    public int OperationId {get;set;}

    public virtual Act Act {get;set;}        
    public virtual Operation Operation {get;set;}    
}
```

В разработке я использую подход *Code First*, для создания связи многие ко многим между `Program` & `Act` в указанный классах я добавляю *навигационные свойства* в `Program`: `public virtual ICollection<Act> Acts {get;set;}`, в `Act`: `public virtual ICollection<Program> Programs {get;set;}`.
т.е. классы стали выглядеть так:

```
public class Program
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int? ActId {get;set;}
    public int OperationId {get;set;}

    public virtual Act Act {get;set;}        
    public virtual Operation Operation {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Act> Acts {get;set;}
}
public class Act
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int OperationId {get;set;}

    public virtual Operation {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Program> Programs {get;set;}
}
```

добавляю миграцию(`add-migration`) и вот что генерируется:

```
public override void Up()
{
    AddColumn("dbo.Acts", "Program_Id", c => c.Int());
    AddColumn("dbo.Programs", "Act_Id", c => c.Int());
    CreateIndex("dbo.Acts", "Program_Id");
    CreateIndex("dbo.Programs", "Act_Id");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.Acts", "Program_Id", "dbo.Programs", "Id");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.Programs", "Act_Id", "dbo.Acts", "Id");
}
```

Хотя я ожидаю создание связующей таблицы приблизительно следующего вида:

```
public class ProgramActs
{
    public int ProgramId {get;set;}
    public int ActId {get;set;}
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста почему так происходит, т.е. не создается необходимая связь?

**P.S.:** *Entity Framework 6.1.3*

**P.S.S.:** Да я знаю, что необходимую мне связь можно создать используя `fluent api`, но хотелось бы понять почему не создается с использованием `data annotations`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У вас в классе Program уже есть свойство `public virtual Act Act { get; set; }`. То есть получается две параллельные связи.

Когда EF смотрит ваши классы - она не может понять какие свойство какому соответствует. Отсюда и проблема.

Решается эта проблема с помощью аннотации [`InverseProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.inversepropertyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public class Program
{
    public virtual Act Act {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Act> Acts {get;set;}
}
public class Act
{
    [InverseProperty("Acts")]
    public virtual ICollection<Program> Programs {get;set;}
}
```

PS не рекомендую оставлять названия навигационных свойств в таком виде - запутаетесь же. Когда связей между сущностями несколько - имя свойства должно говорить о семантике этой связи, а не делаться по шаблону:

```
public class Program
{
    public virtual Act StartingAct {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Act> AllActs {get;set;}
}

public class Act
{
    [InverseProperty("AllActs")]
    public virtual ICollection<Program> UsedIn {get;set;}
}
```

Иначе однажды вы закончите вот так (код реальный):

```
public class AttributeDefinitionRelation 
{
    // Не делайте так никогда!
    public virtual AttributeDefinition AttributeDefinition { get; set; }
    public virtual AttributeDefinition AttributeDefinition1 { get; set; }
    public virtual AttributeDefinition AttributeDefinition2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: поправил вопрос

Comment: огромное спасибо за ответ, на текущий момент две связи между Актом и Программой обусловлено тем что изменились требования, раньше было требование у программы может быть только **один** акт, сейчас же у программы может быть **множество**, переделываю структуру бд, и поэтому 2 навигационных свойства, в последующем останется только одна. подумаю насчет именования свойств: я для себя пока не могу выработать правило именования: `AllActs` || `ActList` || `Acts`

Comment: @Bald в таком случае сразу удаляйте старое свойство, в миграцию допишите SQL-скрипт для преобразования старых данных.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, @Bald коллеги, помогите. не совсем понимаю наличия множества связей в одной таблице. Если есть `AllActs `, как использовать `StartingAct`? На какой из актов он будет указывать (как EF определит чем заполнить данное навигационное св-во)?

Comment: @nikita это не EF определять будет, а программист. На какое укажешь- туда и указывать будет.

Comment: @nikita если Вы хотите в свойстве `StartingAct` получить *первый* акт, то надо будет написать соответствующий запрос: `db.Programs.GroupJoin(acts, p=>p.ActId, a=>a.Id, (p,a)=>new {Program = p, FirstAct = a.FirstOrDefault()})` ну надеюсь идея понятна

Comment: @PavelMayorov т.е. будет использоваться значение ключа ` public int? ActId {get;set;}`? А если бы он отсутствовал в определении класса, EF бы все равно автоматически сгенерировало какой-то внешний ключ в таблице Programs?

Comment: @nikita если я правильно Вас понял, то да. т.е. если бы Вы не определили `ActId` но создали навигационное свойство то `EF` сам бы добавил данное поле

Comment: @Bald, вопрос по вашему комментарию. пока не совсем понятно, каша пока в голове =( 


Вы показываете как использовать это св-во. Т.е. в классе оно у вас для того, чтобы в какой-то момент Вы *сами* могли туда что-то положить. Меня интересует момент создания таблицы. Зачем вы создаете оба св-ва (StartingAct и FirstAct)? Что сделает EF когда увидит такую структуру класса? Создаст 2 внешних ключа?

Что будет в этих св-вах у объекта Program, когда я выполню _context.Programs.FirstOrDefault()?

Comment: в данном конкретном случае у меня два свойства потому что меняется модель(структура таблиц и связей между ними), а обусловлено это тем что я предпочитаю сначала создать и отладить а потом убрать не нужное. да Вы можете создать несколько навигационных свойств, но *заполнять* их придется **самому**, если есть непонимание, то лучше создайте новый вопрос в котором сошлитесь на этот