# Несколько связей двух таблиц Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

Хочу разобраться в навигационных свойствах. Есть класс:

```
public class Order 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public User Customer { get; set; }
    public int SellerId { get; set; }
    public User Seller { get; set; }
}
```

Как видим, тут я пытаюсь 2 раза сослаться на класс User

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Customer")]
    public virtual ICollection<Order> MyOrders { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Seller")]
    public virtual ICollection<Order> OrdersToMe { get; set; }
    public User() { Orders = new List<Order>(); }
}
```

**Вопрос #1:** Навигационное свойство Orders будет выбирать заказы, в которых пользователь Продавец или Покупатель? Как правильно составить запрос?

**Вопрос #2:** Если я хочу добавить связь Многие-ко-Многим между этими таблицами (например, если у Заказа несколько Продавцов, но при этом остается связь Один-ко-Многим для Seller), поможет ли этому добавление Навигационного свойства Sellers в Order? Опять же вопрос об их разделении.

**UPD:** Исправил вопрос с учетом обсуждения [Почему не создается связь Many to Many?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/539638/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8C-many-to-many/539641#539641)

Comment: Вот тут есть пара слов про вашу проблему: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/539641/178779

Comment: @PavelMayorov а второй вопрос решается таким же способом?

Comment: @PavelMayorov и как быть со строкой public User() { Orders = new List<Order>(); }? Она будет такая же?

Comment: `public User() { Orders = new List<Order>(); }` - данная строка инициализации коллекции `Orders` нужна что бы не поймать `Exception` при попытке добавить в *неициализированную* коллекцию экземпляр `Order`

Comment: Навигационное свойство в соответствии с *некой* логикой Вам придется заполнять самому

Comment: @Bald это как?\

Comment: если речь о заполнении навигационного свойства в соответствии с *некой* логикой, то тогда при помощи `linq` запросов, [например](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/539638/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8C-many-to-many/539641#comment681447_539641)

Comment: посмотрите еще вот этот [вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/540033/179270)